# How can I individually address lines in an html table?

Tags: javascript, html-table, dropdown

I have here my small table where I can first choose the gender from a dropdown list. This selection then limits the choices of the second dropdown list.

Now the problem is, if I select for example "Männlich" at the first entry and add a second line over the button, I have there in the second dropdown list the limitation according to the first line where I selected "Männlich".

How can I make the selection for each line individually? Can anyone help me?

```js
$('#selectOption1').on('change', setAnrede);

function setAnrede() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'Männlich') {
    $('.input-field option[value="Sehr geehrte"]').hide();
    $('.input-field option[value="Liebe"]').hide();
    $('.input-field option[value="Werte"]').hide();

    $('.input-field option[value="Sehr geehrter"]').show();
    $('.input-field option[value="Lieber"]').show();
    $('.input-field option[value="Werter"]').show();

  }

  if ($(this).val() === 'Weiblich') {
    $('.input-field option[value="Sehr geehrter"]').hide();
    $('.input-field option[value="Lieber"]').hide();
    $('.input-field option[value="Werter"]').hide();

    $('.input-field option[value="Sehr geehrte"]').show();
    $('.input-field option[value="Liebe"]').show();
    $('.input-field option[value="Werte"]').show();

  }
}


function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[1].type) {
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[1].checked = false;
        break;
    }
  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].querySelector('input[name=chk]');
      if (chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 2) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }


    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="button" value="Empfänger hinzufügen" onclick="addRow('myTable')" />
  <input type="button" value="Empfänger löschen" onclick="deleteRow('myTable')" />
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-scroll">
      <table id="myTable" border=1>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
          <th>Anrede</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <!--                                    <th>Sendedatum</th>-->
          <!--                                    <th>Edit</th>-->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>
              <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <div>
                <label for="selectOption1">Geschlecht angeben:</label>
                <select class="browser-default" id="selectOption1" required>
                  <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                  <option value="Männlich">Männlich</option>
                  <option value="Weiblich">Weiblich</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <div>
                <label for="selectOption2">Anrede angeben:</label>
                <select class="browser-default" id="selectOption2" required>
                  <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                  <option value="Sehr geehrter">Sehr geehrter</option>
                  <option value="Sehr geehrte">Sehr geehrte</option>
                  <option value="Lieber">Lieber</option>
                  <option value="Liebe">Liebe</option>
                  <option value="Werter">Werter</option>
                  <option value="Werte">Werte</option>
                  <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input id="vorname" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input id="nachname" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input id="titel" type="text">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input id="vorname" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </td>
          <!--                                    <td>-->
          <!--                                        <input type="text" class="datepicker validate">-->
          <!--                                    </td>-->
          <!--                                    <td>-->
          <!--                                        <input type='button' class='AddNew' value='+'>-->
          <!--                                    </td>-->
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: for `<input>` elements use the `name=` attribute instead of `id=`. especially, like in your case, when creating additional rows copying your first row, there are multiple elements with the same id's. this should not happen within an html document.in addition, your `$('#selectOption1').on('change', setAnrede);` will never fire on any newly inserted table row, since the event handler is only bind on document load, where those 'to be created' elements doesn't exist. you need event delegation, to bind the event handler.

Comment: Ok thank you for the tipp, i will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i already said in my comment, your dynamic generated rows won't react on the change of your gender, since the click event is not bound. this can be avoided, by changing `$('#selectOption1').on('change', setAnrede);`into

```
$('table').on('change', '.genderSelect', setAnrede);
```

this binds the event to the table, but only fires when the change event matches to a descendant element with the class `.genderSelect` (which you now add to your select box ;) )

first of all, instead of showing/hiding unneeded values, i prefer to set the options only when the gender is chosen. 
additionally, i like to have only on place in my code, where i specify the options of my select boxes. mainly to avoid the `if` statements or errors due to mispelling. 
therefore, in the beginning of the script, i create an object, which i use to populate the options for both select boxes!

```
 var gsAddress = {
   "neutral": ["Guden", "Hallo", "Moin"],
   "male": ["Sehr geehrter", "Werter", "Lieber"],
   "female": ["Sehr geehrte", "Werte", "Liebe"]
 };
```

as i said, i want to populate both select boxes with options using the above object.

the first select box (genderSelect), needs a new function, which gets called within the document ready function:

```
$(".genderSelect").each(prefillGenderSelect); //don't forget to add the class to the select element

function prefillGenderSelect() {
   var curSelBox = this; //assign the current context to a variable
   $.each(gsAddress, function(key, value) { // loop through the object, created above
     var newOption = $('<option/>', {
       'value': key, // the current gender where you're cycling through
       'class': 'anyClass', // add any needed classes for <option>
       'text': key // same again as value (but can be different)
     }).appendTo(curSelBox);
   })
 }
```

as soon as you change the genderSelect, the setAnrede fires and populates the gsAddress select box with its options.
my setAnrede function, looks like this:

```
function setAnrede() {
   var myRow = $(this).closest("tr"); // travel up your DOM
   var curSelectBox = myRow.find(".gsAddress"); //travel down your DOM and find your select Box
   $(curSelectBox).find("option").remove(); //wipe out all existing options

   $.each(gsAddress[$(this).val()], function(index, value) { //gs for gender specific

     var newOption = $('<option/>', {
       'value': value, // the current gsAdress where you're cycling through
       'class': 'anyClass', // add any needed classes for <option>
       'text': value // same again as value(but can be different)
     }).appendTo(curSelectBox);
   });
 }
```

for your 'add row' button. instead of copying the first row, you should define a default row as object and simply append it to your table. this would look similar to the 'option' object created earlier

```
var defaultRow = $("<tr/>"); //if there are attributes like class and id needed, add them like in the option declaration.

var exampleCell = $("<td/>", {    //every cell needs to be defined, ofc
  'class' : 'aTableCell'         //if you need to add class information to the td
  }
$(defaultRow).append(exampleCell); //and if it is created, append it into your row
$("#myTable").append(defaultRow); // in the end, just append the complete row to your table
```

i've created a working fiddle. but i reduced the html to the minimum needed and also implemented a simple addRow button, using the .clone() function of jquery. this was only there, to see if it's still working on new rows. 
.clone() also copies id's of elements, when they exist. so cloning shouldn't be done, if id's are needed...
here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/sbtywfjL/

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put in. Unfortunately I don't fully understand the setAnrede function. I'm not sure how to get this to work in my code now.

Comment: hey @Adrian, i just updated the solution with the complete set anrede function. and a link to a working fiddle.

Comment: this is awesome. Thank you very much for your effort, This works perfect.